# Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Firefox and Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

Hi all I am trying to write a script to mimic clicking on a website. However, I face this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:/YetLin/testbb.py", line
>   44, in 
>       yearselect.select_by_value("2")   File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py",
>   line 81, in select_by_value
>       self._setSelected(opt)   File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py",
>   line 211, in _setSelected
>       option.click()   File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
>   line 74, in click
>       self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)   File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
>   line 457, in _execute
>       return self._parent.execute(command, params)   File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 233, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 194, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message:
>   Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Here's an image of the elements, and the following is my code. Could anyone please help? :)

[image]

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
url = 'https://appworld.blackberry.com/isvportal/login.do'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

element = driver.find_element_by_id("ssoLogin")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
username = driver.find_element_by_name("formId:email")
password = driver.find_element_by_name("formId:password")

username.send_keys("yyy")
password.send_keys("xxx")

driver.find_element_by_name("formId:logincommandLink").click()

driver.find_element_by_link_text('Reports').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Schedule').click()


driver.implicitly_wait(3)

driver.find_element_by_id("s2id_fetchTypesSelect")



driver.find_element_by_id("s2id_fetchTypesSelect")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#fetchTypesSelect").click()
yearselect = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#fetchTypesSelect"))
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
yearselect.select_by_value("2")
```

The whole thing is a drop down list. That will only show after you click on the "Please select a type". I want to get the "Download Summary"

[image]

Comment: Try scrolling up/down to that element then selecting it. That may work.

Comment: can you visually confirm that the element is visible while the script is running?

Comment: thanks for your comment! however, the drop down list dont require scrolling (manual clicking).

Comment: Also can you paste the exact error from console ?

Comment: @HassanMehmood hmm, what do you mean by that? I will screenshot what I see before and after clicking the "Please select a type"

Comment: yeah that will be helpful, the screenshots

Comment: @HassanMehmood uploaded the contents, please take a look.

Comment: Try the script I have posted in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it :)
posting my answers here if anyone might need it.

What I did was to use the search text box to get the option that I wanted.

```html
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="s2id_fetchTypesSelect"]/a/span[1]').click()
time.sleep(1)
#driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#fetchTypesSelect')

time.sleep(1)

search= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select2-drop"]/div/input')
search.click()
search.send_keys('Download Summary')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select2-drop"]/ul/li/div').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem before. The fact is that the select element is hidden, in fact the class is hidden-field. The selenium driver cannot see it.

Comment: I didn't solve it. In fact, if you'll find a solution, I'll be glad to use it!

Comment: @MatteoFelici its not selenium issue. problem is that element is not visible in browser window.

Comment: @MatteoFelici I managed to get it! see if my code in the answer section helps you :)